# Are SVG images well supported enough to use in emails?

Tags: email, magento, svg

I am looking to replace the default logo in all our Magento transactional emails.

Using the "Welcome Email" template as a test, I've added our logo as an SVG file. This displays fine with all of the different email accounts I am able to test.

Is using SVG images in emails considered to be acceptable practice or should I switch to using a different format?

Comment: As with a lot of CSS, email clients are woefully inadequate at display and it's quite easy to shoot yourself in the foot trying out stuff that's "too new".

Answer (score 4):

Here are the [results of SVG background in email test](http://conference.createsend.com/screens/r/06A83737A07C505E?kmi=HkMGXVvv3pujgtt7V3y%2FkFCb4vY%3D&__utma=193339890.186778941.1414852873.1414852873.1414852873.1&__utmb=193339890.1.10.1414852873&__utmc=193339890&__utmx=-&__utmz=193339890.1414852873.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=%28referral%29|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/5681562/svg-image-not-showing-in-html-email&__utmv=193339890.|1=user-type=prospect=1&__utmk=222001240&_ga=1.187319848.186778941.1414852873).

From this test, I would say that most clients don't support it well enough.